# Why does my list return only last row?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am using a list and filling it from the database.

```
public List<HimHer.Models.Stories> GetAllImages()
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("Select * from Images", con);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcom);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dt = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();


            List<HimHer.Models.Stories> list = new List<Stories>();

            Stories st = new Stories();

            while (dt.Read()) 
            {


                st.Image = dt["Image"].ToString();
                st.Story = dt["Story"].ToString();
            }


            list.Add(st);

            return list;




        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Stories model has only 2 properties such as Story, Image.

but my list returns only last row, why? I want it to return all rows.

Comment: Because you need to put both `Stories st = new Stories();` and `list.Add(st);` **inside** the `while` loop

Comment: To clarify the reason why both need to go inside the loop - list.Add(st) adds a reference to the list, if you do not create a new object each time around the loop you will get multiple references to the same object which you are overwriting each time.

Comment: I would suggest you consider using a lightweight ORM like https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco to do this style of mapping automatically for you.

Answer (score 9):

Because you only ever add one element to the list:

```
Stories st = new Stories();
while (dt.Read()) 
{
    st.Image = dt["Image"].ToString();
    st.Story = dt["Story"].ToString();
}
list.Add(st);
```

Instead, add *every* element to the list:

```
while (dt.Read()) 
{
    Stories st = new Stories();
    st.Image = dt["Image"].ToString();
    st.Story = dt["Story"].ToString();
    list.Add(st);
}
```

Side note: Your `catch` block is superfluous and actually detrimental to exception handling and debugging.  You should just remove it entirely.

Comment: If you don't expect to do anything else with the `st` variable, is there any drawback to instantiating within the `list.Add` method? `list.Add( new Stories { Image = dt["Image"].ToString(), Story = dt["Story"].ToString()  } )`. I understand this isn't how the OP structured it, but I'm bringing it up as an alternative.

Comment: @jnthnjns: The only drawback I could see would be if separate statements are useful for debugging in this particular case.  Otherwise I personally would do exactly what you suggest.  There's really no performance difference between the two.  If one is micro-optimizing at that level then there are likely much more significant bottlenecks to address first.

Comment: Well said. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add list inside the while:

```
public List<HimHer.Models.Stories> GetAllImages()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("Select * from Images", con);
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcom);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dt = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();


                List<HimHer.Models.Stories> list = new List<Stories>();

                Stories st; 
                while (dt.Read()) 
                {

                    st= new Stories();
                    st.Image = dt["Image"].ToString();
                    st.Story = dt["Story"].ToString();
                    list.Add(st);
                }




                return list;




            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Since having list outside the while will add only last stored values

Comment: Wrong - `Stories st = new Stories();` must be inside the loop

Comment: You will find that OP gets multiple copies of the last entry.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, you are right, I was editing the same. Not good at typing :)

Comment: @PaulF yes multiple copies. Why ? an instance of stories is an instance whether outside or inside

Comment: @StackyUnderflow: see my comment to the original question - basically it will be the same instance if you create it outside the loop. list.Add() does not create a copy of what you are adding.

Comment: @StackyUnderflow: Exactly... ***an*** instance.  One single instance.  You need to create multiple instances and add all of them to the list, rather than create only a single instance and keep modifying it and re-adding it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue here is your "Add" method is placed after the while loop has finished executing.

```
public List<HimHer.Models.Stories> GetAllImages()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("Select * from Images", con);
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcom);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dt = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();

                List<HimHer.Models.Stories> list = new List<Stories>();

                while (dt.Read()) 
                {
                    Stories st = new Stories();
                    st.Image = dt["Image"].ToString();
                    st.Story = dt["Story"].ToString();
                    list.Add(st);
                }
                return list;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```